# Import IsThereAnyDeal waitlist to Google sheets

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import my full wishlist from IsThereAnyDeal.com be default it will only load 75 results until you scroll down, so I feel i may need to start working with their API.

I've attempted using links like this as an example, however it searches the list of games on the site. https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v02/search/search/?key=&q=hades

I'm looking to do this automatically to avoid manually exporting this periodically

For reference, here's the current waitlist and what I expect I'll be importing from https://isthereanydeal.com/u/01bc9/waitlist/

Comment: You will probably want to learn how to use [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String,Object))

Comment: That's what I was thinking Cooper, I just haven't determined everything i need to make that work

Comment: Can I ask you about the official document of API you want to use?

Comment: Sorry, yes, here's the official documentation for this api https://itad.docs.apiary.io/#reference/waitlist

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- From [your provided official document](https://itad.docs.apiary.io/#reference/waitlist), I thought that you might use the method of "Waitlist" in "Waitlist".
- When I saw the sample curl command, it is as follows.

  ```
    curl --include \
    'https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v01/user/wait/all/?access_token=###'
  ```
- And, the sample response is as follows.

  ```
    {
      "data": {
        "falloutnewvegas": {
          "title": "Fallout: New Vegas"
        },
        "racesun": {
          "title": "Race the Sun"
        },
        "vessel": {
          "title": "Vessel"
        }
      }
    }
  ```
- You want to achieve above request using Google Apps Script.
- And, you have already got the valid access token for using the API.

If my understanding is correct, when above curl command is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save it. And, please set the variables of `accessToken` and `sheetName`, and run the function.

```
function myFunction() {
  const accessToken = "###"; // Please set your access token.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";  // Please set the sheet name.

  // Retrieve the values from API.
  const url = "https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v01/user/wait/all/?access_token=" + accessToken;
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  console.log(res.getContentText()) // You can confirm the response value at the log.
  const obj = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());

  // Put the retrieved values to Spreadsheet.
  const values = Object.entries(obj.data).map(([k, {title}]) => [k, title]);
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

- If an error occurs for the access token and the access token includes the specific characters, please modify `const url = "https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v01/user/wait/all/?access_token=" + accessToken;` to `const url = "https://api.isthereanydeal.com/v01/user/wait/all/?access_token=" + encodeURIComponent(accessToken);`

#### Note:

- In this sample script, it supposes that your access token can be used for the API. Please be careful this.
- Unfortunately, from your question, I couldn't find the output situation you expect. But I understood that you want to put the retrieved values to the Spreadsheet. So in this sample script, the key and the title of the value are put to the Spreadsheet. When you want to change the format, please modify above script.
- When I saw the official document you provided, it says `Get list of games that the user has in Waitlist.`. But I couldn't find the document about the number of response values. So I'm not sure about the maximum number of response values for this method.

#### References:

- [Waitlist of official document](https://itad.docs.apiary.io/#reference/waitlist/waitlist/get-user%27s-waitlist)
- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I'll try it out within the next day. I'm still very new with scripts and APIs. The big thing I've had trouble understanding is where do I get the accesstoken from. Do I come up with that or do I need to grab that from somewhere?

Comment: @Charles Thank you for replying. When my answer was not useful for your situation, I apologize. About your new question of `The big thing I've had trouble understanding is where do I get the accesstoken from. Do I come up with that or do I need to grab that from somewhere?`, I would like to recommend to check [the official document](https://itad.docs.apiary.io/#reference/oauth-authentication/authorize). If you cannot understand about it, I would like to recommend to contact to the stuffs at the API side or post it as new question. I apologize I'm not familiar with the API you use.

Comment: THANK YOU for all your help! I went to the isthereanydeal app site, added a redirect uri and a url where the app is available (both are fictitious) before I could authorize my app to read my wishlist. Afterwards I grabbed the token out of the address bar and inserted it into the code you provided, it's now working perfectly! I just need to work with parsing the data to have it display the way i'm expecting.

Comment: @Mathx2 Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.